# How can I calculate spearman correlation using scipy in python?

Tags: python, scipy, bioinformatics, data-science

I have a python script that generates z scores from gene expression data. I also want the script to create a spearman correlation output. I want to know the correlation among the replicates. So in the output the rows and columns would both be the replicates names.

I haven't found any examples of how to use scipy to calculate spearman rank correlation of more than 2 lists. Can I use scipy's stats.spearmanr to compare all the replicates in one command? I have the data stored in a string. Here is some of my code:

```
t_vals=[]
z_outline = []
z_outlines = []

header = None
for line in input_file:
    line = formatLine(line)
    if line.startswith("#"):
        header = line
        header += "\n"
        z_output.write(header)
        sp_output.write(header)
        continue
    lineList = line.split("\t")

    vals = []
    in_vals =[]
    for item in lineList[1:]:
        val = float(item)
        in_vals.append(val)
        vals.append(val)

    median = robjects.r['mean'](robjects.FloatVector(vals))[0]
    mad = robjects.r['sd'](robjects.FloatVector(vals))[0]
    z_vals = []
    t_vals = []

    for v in in_vals:
        if mad == 0:
            z_val = (v - median) / CLOSE_TO_ZERO
        else:
            z_val = (v - median) / mad

        z_vals.append(z_val)
        t_vals.append(z_val)

    z_vals_str = []
    for v in t_vals:
        z_vals_str.append("%.4f" % v)

    z_outline = "\t".join(lineList[:1]) + "\t"
    z_outline += "\t".join(z_vals_str)
    z_outline += "\n"

    z_outlines.append(z_outline)


for outline in z_outlines:
    z_output.write(outline + "\n")
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Hard to help you without any example data. In principle, scipy.stats.spearmanr is fine, although the output format is a bit weird if your inputs a and b are 2-D.

Comment: I think Spearman correlation is only defined for two vectors at a time. You can look at all pairwise Spearman correlations or average each replicate set and then find the Spearman between these two averaged vectors.

Comment: Please include the code in which you are trying to use spearman correlation. The code you post look like a file formating